# Hundreds of streams are allocated on the server when using gRPC in Android requests

Tags: android, grpc

I use gRPC from Google for work with server, but after some time I notices that streams are allocated on server and only when I close my app they closes.

```
        GatewayGrpc.GatewayBlockingStub stub = getGatewayBlockingStub();
        Gw.GetRequest request = new Gw.GetRequest();
        request.authToken = authToken;
        request.requestId = requestId;
        Gw.GetResponse response = stub.get(request);
```

How to release this connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "hundreds of streams" you meant "hundreds of connections," then you probably aren't shutting down the `ManagedChannel`. `getGatewayBlockingStub()` is probably internally creating a `ManagedChannel`. You need to call `ManagedChannel.shutdown()`.

Normally Channels are to be reused. Channels lazily initialize any TCP connections and don't reconnect unless there are new RPCs.

Comment: I am using one static connection ManagedChannel for all requests. Why connections grows? It is a bug, or I do somethings wrong?

Comment: @IhorKostenko, multiple connections can be used when the server sends GOAWAY. A new connection will be started and the old may remain until all RPCs on it complete. That normally won't produce too many extra connections. Approximately how many connections are you seeing after how many RPCs?

Comment: @IhorKostenko, looking at the title again, if you're seeing hundreds of connections, that's almost certainly a bug. It's possible it's caused by the same problem (broken shutdown handling) [I reference in a backport PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/1894). Hundreds of connections is far more than I would believe a bug in that code could cause, so filing a [new issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/new) for us to follow up make be apt.